# Unable to edit certain category fields in magento 1.6

Tags: php, javascript, magento, e-commerce

I’m having a problem saving certain fields in certain categories when I go to edit them in Magento 1.6. For example I can’t edit the following fields in these categories:

- america/mini packages - description
- america/flights - meta description
- america/cruises - page title
- australia/tours/independent tours - page title
- australia/motorhomes - meta description

Occasionally you can make a change and save it but then when you try and make another save it just won’t save the changes. there doesnt appear to be a pattern in this otherwise I could try and track the issue down a little better. There doesnt appear to be any javascript errors when i save the category.

I really need to get this issue fixed and I can’t find a solution to the issue anywhere.

Thanks in advance for your help.

These are the last few lines in system.log

```
2012-03-15T12:52:36+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] /home/strailco   /1stclassholidays.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:51
[1] /home/strailco/1stclassholidays.com/html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:766
[2] /home/strailco/1stclassholidays.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:82
[3] /home/strailco/1stclassholidays.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:188
[4] /home/strailco/1stclassholidays.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:349
[5] /home/strailco/1stclassholidays.com/html/app/Mage.php:640
[6] /home/strailco/1stclassholidays.com/html/index.php:80
</pre>
2012-03-15T12:52:36+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] /home/strailco/1stclassholidays.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:51
[1] /home/strailco/1stclassholidays.com/html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:766
[2] /home/strailco/1stclassholidays.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:82
[3] /home/strailco/1stclassholidays.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:188
[4] /home/strailco/1stclassholidays.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:349
[5] /home/strailco/1stclassholidays.com/html/app/Mage.php:640
[6] /home/strailco/1stclassholidays.com/html/index.php:80
</pre>
```

Comment: Check your logs and post 'em. Intermittent saving problems when the data you are trying to save is the same would suggest an issue with the server.

Comment: @Zachary Schuessler I have added the error logs to the main question. Could you have a look and see if you can see an issue. I'm not sure what to look for. Many Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Very likely an issue with a plugin you have installed. There are several good resources for tracking down the specific issue. Alan Storm has two excellent answers on this question: [Magento Debug HEADERS ALREADY SENT error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670031/magento-debug-headers-already-sent-error)