# Understanding the Magento Error Log Output

Tags: magento, error-handling

Magento's error handling is a bit confusing for me, a novice in the Magento world. However, I need to learn to understand them as best I can to continue to grow in my current position at work. However, maybe it's just me, but I find it hard to find clear-cut information to help troubleshoot newcomers to Magento - as other systems have.

So, I come here in hopes someone can clear something up for me.

Is there a resource online or even documentation to help me understand the error log output? My latest error log that I'm attempting to fix is the following:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:174:"Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /Desktop/root/THEME_NAME/app/code/local/Ryomagento/VB/controllers/OptionsController.php, line 195";i:1;s:1609:"#0 /Desktop/root/THEME_NAME/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(148): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)

#1 /Desktop/root/THEME_NAME/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php(105): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setRedirect('http://nbc.loca...', 302)

#2 /Desktop/root/THEME_NAME/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(672): Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http->setRedirect('http://nbc.loca...')

#3 /Desktop/root/THEME_NAME/app/code/local/Ryomagento/VB/controllers/OptionsController.php(166): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->_redirect('checkout/cart/')

#4 /Desktop/root/THEME_NAME/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Ryomagento_VisualBadge_OptionsController->postAction()

#5 /Desktop/root/THEME_NAME/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('post')

#6 /Desktop/root/THEME_NAME/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))

#7 /Desktop/root/THEME_NAME/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()

#8 /Desktop/root/THEME_NAME/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

#9 /Desktop/root/THEME_NAME/index.php(92): Mage::run('nbc', 'website')

#10 {main}";s:3:"url";s:25:"/VB/options/post";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:13:"nationalbadge";}
```

Some things to note:

- This is currently on my local development install.
- What we're attempting to to pass information from one system within a iFrame, to our shopping cart. It works on currently deployed sites but not a newly created store I'm preparing locally. It seems somewhere along the line, a break is occurring when the item is actually hitting the cart - because the HTTP Header is being sent two many commands.
- Beyond this preliminary knowledge of the problem, I'm unsure currently...

As I said, I'm no expert. Just passionate and want to learn more in Magento especially. This is my first time having to deal with HTTP Headers and transferring data via URL from an iFrame to a cart. While I know what's occurring in theory, I wouldn't be able to describe it in great detail.

Thanks for any help anyone can provide!! I just really want to be able to understand these logs. Can only help. Love the Stack community...

Comment: Anyone? Pulling my hair out and getting no where...

Answer (score 0):

I can understand your frustrations, we all had our growing pains.  It means that the module that is throwing the error is attempting to fetch headers after they have already been set and sent for output.  I would love to type you a large and direct answer but this is one of those errors that you have to do some tracing with. Please look at the SO answer as it should lead you to the correct answer.  [Magento Debug HEADERS ALREADY SENT error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670031/magento-debug-headers-already-sent-error)

Comment: Thank you so much!! I will look into this ASAP. Yeah, the "growing" within Magento sure is painful. :P