# improper XML rendered from magento custom module controller

Tags: magento, module

I got into trouble rendering XML from controller.

I have tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/4442879/647723

If I do -

```
$this->getResponse()->setBody($xmlContent);
```

I get "Headers already sent", even if I used

```
$response->clearHeader() method.
```

If I do -

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
//$this->loadLayout(false);
echo $xmlContent;
//$this->renderLayout();
exit();
```

I get the desired output but the note the desired formatting. Chrome, Firefox show them as bunch of text. To generate xml for $xmlContent, I used SimpleXml tool. Can you help so that I can render dynamic XML properly on screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it. There was a space before the php tag in the controller class. And that drove me nuts. For others in similar issues, make sure your controller is compact.